# Export module with slash paths

Tags: typescript

I am working on a typescript module library project.
I have main index.ts configured in package.json where all my external exports happen.
I have quite complicated internal modules that need to be exported and to organize things better I tried namespacing. But this results in the library users to do imports with dots. For example,

```
import { Shape } from 'mylib';
let triangle = new Shape.Triangle();
```

What I want is something like this.

```
import { Triangle } from 'mylib/shape';
```

How do I export so that I can achieve slash path imports?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own lib structure and export from index at every level. For example if you want your lib to be named 'MyLib' then the structure should be like:

```
- Public
- Src
- MyLib
 |- MyLibContent
   |- ExampleComponentFolder 
   |- index.ts ( export * from './ExampleComponentFolder' )
 |- index.ts ( export * from './MyLibContent' )
```

with this you can now have a file in Src that uses MyLib just like any other lib such as this:

```
-- Src
  |- MyComponent.tsx

import {Triangle } from 'MyLib' // or if you define as lib '@MyLib'
export const MyComponent = () => {
  return <Triangle/>
}
```